# How can i have same html for multiple categories or pages and then add specific or different data from database to them in django restframework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-templates

In this program i have these two functions in my `views.py`:

```
def home(request):
    p=product.objects.all()
    return render(request,'home.html',{'p':p})

def foods(request):
    p=product.objects.all()
    return render(request,'foods.html',{'p':p})
```

They both have access to the same data from database i mean if i want to post some json with django restframework then `foods` and `home` will have the same data because they have the same html:

```html
    <div class="grid">  
        {% for i in p%} 
                
                    <div class='card'>
                        <img src="{{i.image}}"></img>
                        <p id="id">{{i.description}}</p>
                        <a href="{{i.buy}}" target='_blank' rel='noopener noreferrer'>
                            <button><span class="price"> ${{i.price}}</span> buy</button>
                        </a>    




                    </div>

        {%endfor%}
    </div>
```

it is good for me to have  just one html for multiple pages and then access to different data from  database but if i add some json both of them will contain the same data(for some reason data of `foods` is empty but it will generate the same number of products based on json like `home`)

I want to know how can you have same html for multiple categories or pages and then add specific or different data from database to them?

### More details:

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
 
# Create your models here.
class product(models.Model):
     
     
    image=models.CharField(max_length=500)
    description=models.CharField(max_length=500)
    price=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    buy=models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

---

serializers.py:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import product
 


class productSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model= product
        fields="__all__"
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import *
from rest_framework import viewsets,status
from .serializers import productSerializer
from rest_framework.parsers import JSONParser
from django.http import HttpResponse,JsonResponse
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.decorators import action

class productviewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset=product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = productSerializer 

    def create(self, request):
        serialized = productSerializer(data=request.data, many=True)
        if serialized.is_valid():
            serialized.save()
            return Response(serialized.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serialized._errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    @action (detail=False , methods=['post']) 
    def delete(self,request):
        product.objects.all().delete()
        return Response('success')
def home(request):
    p=product.objects.all()
    return render(request,'home.html',{'p':p})

def foods(request):
    p=product.objects.all()
    return render(request,'foods.html',{'p':p})
```

If i have 20 categories with 20 different pages  i will never create 20 different databases if there is a way for those categories to access specifically from the same database.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly and you will have a certain amount of goods divided into 20 categories, then I somehow used this
You need to create a separate model for the categories, and in the product model add a foreign key to the category

**models.py**

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, db_index=True, unique=True)
    
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('shop:product_list_by_category',
                        args=[self.slug])

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name



class Product(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='products')
    available = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    ...
```

views.py

```
def product_list(request, category_slug=None):
    category = None
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    products = Product.objects.filter(available=True)
    if category_slug:
        category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=category_slug)
        products = products.filter(category=category)
    return render(request,
                  'shop/product/list.html',
                  {'category': category,
                   'categories': categories,
                   'products': products})
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'shop'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.product_list, name='product_list'),
    path('<category_slug>', views.product_list, name='product_list_by_category'),
]
```

html

```
{% block content %}
    <div id="main" class="product-list">
        <h1>{% if category %}{{ category.name }}{% else %}Products{% endif %}</h1>
        {% for product in products %}
            <div class="item">
               <img src="{% if product.image %}{{ product.image.url }}{% else %}{% static "img/no_image.png" %}{% endif %}">
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```